# gdal_merge was unexpected at this time

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

I am using gdal_merge to create an raster from around 250 files (rasters). when I run the command i got **gdal_merge was unexpected at this time**

The command is correct as if I split the files it works fine

gdal_merge -o "Z:\30cm Imagery 2015 original\test.tif" "Z:\50cm Imagery 2015 original\jp2\15003800.jp2" "Z:\50cm Imagery 2015 original\jp2\15003850.jp2"

Comment: Why merge, use GDALbuildVRT to create a tileset of the images. How are you accessing the command via CMD or a shell of some sort? Surely it should be gdal_merge.py -o xxxxxxx xxx xx to instruct the operating system to use python to execute the command.

Comment: I need one Image to be used in ArcGIS, I am not sure ArcGIS support GDALbuildVRT. I am using the command from CMD

Comment: ArcMap supports VRT... but if you're using Esri try the Mosaic Dataset http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000037000000 (new in ArcGis 10) as a hypertile (sort of). It doesn't import the images but references them in situ as index and it's really fast until you try to export as a single image - but even that's faster than mosaicing.

Comment: Are you running a batch with variables? This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769591/was-unexpected-at-this-time

Comment: You can also first convert images into a virtual mosaic with gdalbuildvrt  and then materialize it into to physical image with gdal_translate `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=jpeg input.vrt output.tif`